# cant install "additional driver"

Tags: drivers

I uninstalled the "additional driver" app from the ubuntu software center.
After that ,when I tried reinstalling it ,I am getting this error- **Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

How can I reinstall it again?

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: this @Avinash Raj-
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  jockey-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 438 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get autoremove` command.After that try to install additional driver.If it still shows the error then post it's error report.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It got installed. BTW, being novice linux user,could you explain what was the problem

Comment: Yes. It worked.While you post the answer,also do explain what posssibly might have caused the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` command shows,

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: 
jockey-common 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 438 not upgraded
```

The above error report shows clearly that you have to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` command to automatically remove all the unused packages.In your case it's `jockey-common`. While running `sudo apt-get autoremove` command, it removes automatically `jockey-common` package.And also `sudo apt-get install -f` will solve dependency problems.